# Trying to clear one character from TextView

Tags: android

I made a calculator app and I made a `clear` Button that clears the TextView.

```
private TextView _screen;
private String display = "";

private void clear() {
    display = "";
    currentOperator = "";
    result = "";
}
```

I got this code from Tutorial and set the clear button `onClick` to `onClickClear`, so it do that part of the code and it works. Now I have made this code delete only one number at a time and it don't work. What can be done to delete only one number at a time?

```
public void onClickdel(View v) {
    display = "";
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below code will delete one char from textView.

```
String display = textView.getText().toString();

if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(display)) {
    display  = display.substring(0, display.length() - 1);

    textView.setText(display);
}
```

Comment: thank you so match sir you answer was great and worked great

Comment: but when i press the button with no number on the app crash

Comment: You're Welcome Friend :)

Comment: Updated the answer have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the string and not the textview.

**To clear the TextView use:**

```
_screen.setText("");
```

**To remove the last character:**

```
String str = _screen.getText().toString();
if(!str.equals(""))
    str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
_screen.setText(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String display = textView.getText().toString();

    if(!display.isEmpty()) {

    textView.setText(display.substring(0, display.length() - 1));   
}
```